# How to return an error but continue to retry in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using [`react-query`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) to fetch the data from the backend.

When the user views the page, optionally there is still no data in the backend, so **the backend will return `404`**, and the user **will see an EmptyState** component.

Now, I want to show the **EmptyState** component, but continue to *refetch*/*retry* in the background.

How can achieve that with `react-query`?

---

I tried to use "infinite retry", but when the `react-query` is retrying, it still returns `isLoading = true`, and I can't show the **EmptyState** meanwhile.

I also thought to use `refetchInterval`, but if, for example, I set it to 30 seconds, I don't want it to be 30 minutes when a data is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-query will only go error state after all the retries have finished. I see multiple options:

1. use `refetchInterval` like you suggested yourselves. You can set it to a function to derive if you want to enable the interval or not, depending on the data:

```
refetchInterval: (data, query) => query.state === 'error' ? 5000 : 0
```

this would refetch every 5 seconds for as long as the query is in error state. If it goes to success, the interval is disabled.

2. use the retries, and react-query will give you a `failureCount: boolean` returned from `useQuery`. This count will update every time the query fails and gets retried internally. The failure count will go back to `0` as soon as the query is successful, or, as soon as you restart a fetch.

so you could display your empty state while `failureCount > 0`